# Can Uranium-238 undergo ordinary (single) beta decay?

Tags: nuclear-physics, radiation, radioactivity, isotopes

Can U-238 undergo regular, single beta decay?

Are there isotopes which can only undergo double, never single, beta decay?  Not even two normal beta decays in quick succession?

Answer (score 1):

The U238 (and some other isotopes) can't decay with single beta, but only with [double beta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_beta_decay), because of energetic reasons. The decay product of single beta would have higher energy than the energy of the original nucleus, but with double beta they can decay into a lower energy state. (Look at the isotope masses of [U238](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotopes_of_uranium), [Np238](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotopes_of_neptunium) and [Pu238](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotopes_of_plutonium), higher mass means higher energy.)

Comment: Note that while double-beta decay from U to Pu is energetically allowed, it has never been observed.

Comment: At least not directly, the wiki says in the "method" field that it was observed radiochemically.